# A service account has "Compute Admin" permission but an error says that compute.instances.list is needed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

My goal is waking up / shutting down a GCE instance regularly.

https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule

I set up "Cloud Scheduler" and "Cloud Functions" as written in the link.

Next, I tested Cloud Function, then the following error was reported.

```
Error: function crashed. Details:
Required 'compute.instances.list' permission for 'projects/[project-id]'
```

Thus I added the "Compute Admin" permission to the **service account which is used by Cloud Function**, but the same error was reported.

In addition I changed VM instance's policy to allow Cloud API to use any API, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Function and GCE are in the same project ?

Comment: You have assigned the Compute Admin role to the wrong service account. Cloud Functions by default uses the App Engine Default Service Account. The role `roles/compute.admin` has `compute.instances.list`.

Comment: Re-created these functions, then they ran.(but the instance wouldn't stop.)

Comment: @yutaaa did you make sure that the VM instance is in the same project and region the Cloud Functions are? I have been able to follow the guide and successfully start/stop a VM with the functions subscribed to a Pub/Sub topic.

Answer (score 3):

There are two service accounts used by GCF:

- Cloud Functions service account
- Runtime service account

The Cloud Functions service account `service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com` is used to create/update/delete functions.

On the other hand, the Runtime service account `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com, App Engine default service account`
is used by functions to access other GCP resources at runtime.

So you need to add `Compute Admin` to the Runtime service account.

Comment: There might be a bug.
I assigned the right to the correct SA at the first time after creating function, then it doesn't work.
However, I re-created the functions, then they ran.(but the instance wouldn't stop.)